# AS3 and the loader class

Tags: actionscript, flash, arrays, loader

I write here, because after looking for a solution, I could not resolve my error...

```
var test:MovieClip;

var sign:Loader = new Loader();  
sign.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completSIGN);  
sign.load(new URLRequest("http://files.zebest-3000.com/278374/3011/3011.swf"));  

function completSIGN(e:Event):void  
{  
test = MovieClip(e.target.content);  
addChild(test);  
}
```

This is the error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Il est impossible d'accéder à la propriété ou à la méthode d'une référence d'objet nul. at Main::StateManager()

So, the movie (some videos work perfectly and others not) does not want to load in my container ; it seems there is a problem in the mapping... and can't modify the distant movie.

- Is there an other method of loading a movie inside one other (I have try also to load with bytearray, but it's the same)?
- Can we catch this error and relocate the instance to help him to find the correct way?

Comment: What is null at that line in StateManager? I'm not seeing how StateManager is related to this code.

Comment: if the error is in `StateManager`, then post that code

Comment: StateManager is a part of the distant movie, I haven't the code, but without encapsulation, the movie works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment I assume that `StateManager()` is called from the constructor of the document class of the remote SWF and it tries to access `stage` using something like `this.stage` or `this.root.stage`. Now, it'll work without any issues when run as a standalone SWF because the `stage` property would've been set by the time document class's constructor is called. When loaded remotely `stage` is set only after you add it in the complete handler.

I'm not sure about this, but try calling `addChild(sign);` before you call `sign.load` - you can remove those two lines from the `completeSign` method.

Comment: In that case, the loaded content is created before adding to the display list, which makes perfect sense too, and you're gonna have to contact the author of the `StateManager` to fix it.